# Host file set, ping goes 127.0.0.1, but in browser URL still goes out to web?

Tags: iis, localhost

Having some issues running my code local.

I have host file setup like this:

127.0.0.1        ryan.local.myappname.com

if I ping that URL it kicks back from 127...

but if I browse there in firefox or IE it takes me to an old version of the site that is currently live instead of taking me to the local one...

I am running Windows 7

Any ideas?

copied: https://serverfault.com/questions/65903/host-file-set-ping-goes-127-0-0-1-but-in-browser-url-still-goes-out-to-web

Comment: I think this should be posted at Serverfault.

Comment: @Moayad Mardini: Even if the reason it doesn't work is more of a sysadmin thing I would say this is a fairly programming related issue that could happen to anyone setting up a local version of a site.

Comment: Good call again, now I don't know what to do but leave it in both places haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer per serverfault:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

A common reason for this problem is that you're using a proxy that does the DNS resolving for you. This way your browser never tries to resolve the host name, but simply passes it on to the proxy, which of course doesn't use your host file entry.